# ¿Cómo puedo alinear dos imagenes horizontalmente?

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda y es que como puedo alinear dos imagenes horizontalmente ya que lo he estado probando y no encuentro la manera de como puedo hacerlo , Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria

```
#foto{
    max-width: 55%;
height: auto;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
#foto2{
    max-width: 55%;
height: auto;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te basta con usar la propiedad `display: flex` sobre el `<div>` que contenga tus dos imágenes.

```css
.contenedor-imagenes {
  display: flex;
}

.contenedor-imagenes img:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-imagenes">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1238517872802045953/BsjqKBhn_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1238517872802045953/BsjqKBhn_400x400.jpg">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Añadido margen a la derecha de la primera imagen.

Comment: se podria dejar un pequeño espacio entre las dos imagenes .¿Seria posible?

Comment: Claro, te bastaría con añadir un `margin: right` a la primera imagen. Edité la respuesta para que se vea.

Comment: Muchas Gracias la verdad :D

Comment: Si te valió haz el favor de marcar la respuesta como válida. Se hace marcando el *check* verde que sale junto a la respuesta ^^

Comment: hecho, Muchas Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: como puedo hacer que al hacer responsive la imagen derecha pase abajo del de la izquierda

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar creo que no deberías a usar `max-width : 55%` ya que si ambas imágenes llegaran a alcanzar ese max, eso sumaría más del 100%, por lo cuál entonces una imagen se pasaría abajo.

Para colocar una imagen un lado a otra solo pon `display: inline-bloc`

```css
#foto{
    max-width: 40%;
height: auto;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
}
#foto2{
    max-width: 40%;
height: auto;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id ="foto" src="https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg"/>

<img id ="foto2" src="https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la propiedad grid al igual que flex:
 ejemplo con grid:

```
<style>
    .contenedor{
  background: #EED0C9;

  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px); 
}
.caja_1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #76FF54;
  text-align: center;
}
.caja_2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E97C2B;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="caja_1"> caja 1</div>
  <div class="caja_2">caja 2</div>
</div>
```

[Aqui el enlace a codepen](https://codepen.io/Ruben1985/pen/wvKZWbN?editors=1100)

Ejemplo con flex

```
<style>
  .contenedor{
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    .caja_1{
      background: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    .caja_2{
      background: blue;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
</style>


        <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="caja_1"> caja 1</div>
      <div class="caja_2">caja 2</div>
    </div>
```

[enalce aqui](https://codepen.io/Ruben1985/pen/rNObMBL)